# Decrementing a value in a foreign key model (when creating or updating instances)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I currently have models shown below

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    


class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

As you can see the order model has the product model as a foreign key.

When I create or update instances based upon on the order model, I would like to decrement one value from the stock field in the products model.

See below for the my views for both when creating and updating instances.

```
@login_required
def newOrder(request):
    form = CreateOrderForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('customer_order_list')

    return render(request, 'accounts/new_order.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def editOrder(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    sho = Order.objects.all().values_list('date_created')
    order_date = sho.filter(id=pk)
    form = CreateOrderForm(instance=order)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('customer_order_list')

    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_order.html', {'form': form, 'order_date': order_date})
```

I am aware that using the a similar example below will need to be implemented, however I will have to use  the primary key of that particular instance.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    product = (
        Product.objects
        .select_for_update()
        .get(id=1)
    )
    product.inventory -= 1
    product.save()
```

However this example will not apply for when creating instance based on the order form.

How can one implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to update Product.stock when an Order is made. You can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/) for this. For example:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def update_stock(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.product.stock = instance.product.stock - 1
        instance.product.save()
```